# Investor ID must be filled and length less than or equal to

Tags: fix-protocol

I have got this errors and stuck for couple of days as there is not much resources on the internet.What should be the best possible solution here .

Request:-
=FIXT.1.19=18435=D1128=849=RCL56=TEST50=RCLTRDR00134=252=20211102-10:49:421=120159003542338811=acb1408471447=E452=555=ABBANK762=PUBLIC54=138=100040=244=10529=N60=20211102-10:49:4210=129

Respond:-
8=FIXT.1.19=00040435=849=TEST56=RCL34=257=RCLTRDR00152=20211102-10:49:47.02637=NONE11=acb1408471453=4448=TTLFIXRCL01447=C452=11448=TTLFIXRCL01447=C452=36448=RCLTRDR001447=C452=12448=RCL447=C452=117=2152150=839=8103=991=120159003542338855=ABBANK762=PUBLIC54=138=100044=1059=0529=N151=014=060=20211102-10:49:46.76158=(1381): Investor ID must be filled and length less than or equal to 1010=250

Comment: Best thing probably is to ask your counterparty what the problem is, i.e. what exactly do they expect from you.

Comment: To add to what Christoph said, "Investor ID" is not a standard FIX field -- it's specific to your counterparty.  This is not a generic FIX problem.

Comment: Also: next time you paste FIX messages, please change the field separator to something visible -- most people use the pipe "|" character.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.